# OpenCV Drawing a circle to track a ball issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm teaching myself OpenCV and wrote the following code today to track a ball rolling across my computer webcam feed and (attempt to) draw a filled in grey circle on to it's centroid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point getBlobCentroid(Mat blobImage);

int main()
{
    Mat bGround, fGround, diff;
    Point p = (500, 280);
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> fGround; //assign frame from camera to newest image
        cvtColor(fGround, fGround, CV_BGR2GRAY); //convert to grayscale

        bGround.create(fGround.size(), fGround.type()); 
        absdiff(bGround, fGround, diff); //subtract current frame from old frame

        threshold(diff, diff, 50, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY); //convert to binary
        erode(diff, diff, NULL, Point(-1,-1), 3, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);

        imshow("Thresholded", diff);

        circle(fGround, getBlobCentroid(diff), 6, 127, -1, 8, 16);
        imshow("Natural Image with Tracking", fGround);

        fGround.copyTo(bGround); //move forward in time
        waitKey(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

Point getBlobCentroid(Mat blobImage)
{
    int rowSum=0, colSum=0, count = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<blobImage.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<blobImage.cols; j++)
        {
            if (blobImage.at<uchar>(i,j) == 255)
            {
                rowSum+=i;
                colSum+=j;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    Point centroid = (rowSum, colSum)/count;
    return centroid;
}
```

However, as evidenced by the attached image - the circle never moves away from the top of the screen - in other words, the centroid.y component is always zero. I wrote a bunch of steps of the calculation to the screen, and it appears as though the searching and additions to rowSum and count and such work - those are nonzero. However, as soon as you calculate the centroid or call it in the circle, that's a no go. Even weirder, I tried making a constant center for the circle Point p = (285, 285) and using that as an argument, and that was a no go as well. Help? Thanks!

-Tony

Answer (score 1):

```
fGround.copyTo(bGround); //move forward in time
// so, that's your idea. compare bg & fg, get the centroid of the diff.
// but then, if you follow your while loop there, (waitkey, back to the top ... )

bGround.create(fGround.size(), fGround.type()); 
// aww, so you're never using, what you copied before

absdiff(bGround, fGround, diff); 
// so, in the end, you're always comparing fGround to an empty bGround img
```

Comment: Not sure that is the problem, as the algorithm is working correctly (at least it seems to be) - I think I remember reading that Mat::create() only overrides data and such if it's not already the same - once I copy fGround to bGround the first time, does the create() statement do anything anymore? Anyway, bGround have to be the same size and type or you can't use absdiff on them. Is there are a better way?